# Javascript GoodPart

Tags: javascript, module, closures

I am newbie to javascript and i read the ebook Javascript GoodPart to learn. There is an example about making Module using function and Closures. But the example is too difficult to understand

```js
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;
        return this;
    };

    String.method('deentityify', function () {
        // The entity table. It maps entity names to
        // characters.
        var entity = {
            quot: '"',
            lt: '<',
            gt: '>'
        };
        return function () {
            // This is the deentityify method. It calls the string
            // replace method, looking for substrings that start
            // with '&' and end with ';'. If the characters in
            // between are in the entity table, then replace the
            // entity with the character from the table. It uses
            // a regular expression (Chapter 7).
            return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g,
                    function (a, b) {
                        var r = entity[b];
                        return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
                    }
            );
        };
    }());
    document.writeln('&lt;&quot;&gt;'.deentityify()); // <">
```

What is it different from

```js
String.method('deentityify', function () {
        // The entity table. It maps entity names to
        // characters.
        var entity = {
            quot: '"',
            lt: '<',
            gt: '>'
        };
        return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g,
                function (a, b) {
                    var r = entity[b];
                    return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
                }
        );
    });
```

Both of them gave the same result. If so, why do they need to make thing become so complex like that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to simply put the difference with out going to the details of which is better.

in the first example, how many ever time you call `.deentityify()`  in your application.  the `var entity = {`  object gets created only once(first time when you call `String.method('deentityify', ..`).  then when you use `deentityify`  multiple time, it uses the closure, and don't create it for every invocation.

but in the second case, each time you call `.deentityify()` , those internal object(entity) is been created, there is no closure as such.

now this is good example of closure, when the `entity` object is bigger or there is multiple object/variables or even other functions. in that case the closure way is great!!

Comment: You're right! Now i understand the closure more. Thank you very much Oxi :)

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla Dev Base writes:

> Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables. In
>   other words, the function defined in the closure 'remembers' the
>   environment in which it was created.

So in first example you return a function not the result (as in the lexical example) and that is a closure. Everything in the scope where the function is returned is remembered - although you should expect that it is not remembered (var entidy) and you should expect the code to fail. However they wanted to show that it still works as in the lexical example and how you define closures. However that example is not very practical, you will need to look at other literature or StackOverflow to find more practical examples, e.g. in my [blog](http://meshfields.de/event-listeners-for-loop/).

**Sources**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 0):

**It won't work.**

Adding feature[method "method"] to add custom methods to objects of any class.

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;
        return this;
    };
```

Adding a custom method to every object of String class

```
String.method('deentityify', function () {
        // The entity table. It maps entity names to
        // characters.
        var entity = {
            quot: '"',
            lt: '<',
            gt: '>'
        };
        return function () {
            // This is the deentityify method. It calls the string
            // replace method, looking for substrings that start
            // with '&' and end with ';'. If the characters in
            // between are in the entity table, then replace the
            // entity with the character from the table. It uses
            // a regular expression (Chapter 7).
            return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g,
                    function (a, b) {
                        var r = entity[b];
                        return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
                    }
            );
        };
    }());
```

Calling that custom method

```
'&lt;&quot;&gt;'.deentityify()
```

With just

```
String.method('deentityify', function () {
        // The entity table. It maps entity names to
        // characters.
        var entity = {
            quot: '"',
            lt: '<',
            gt: '>'
        };
        return function () {
            // This is the deentityify method. It calls the string
            // replace method, looking for substrings that start
            // with '&' and end with ';'. If the characters in
            // between are in the entity table, then replace the
            // entity with the character from the table. It uses
            // a regular expression (Chapter 7).
            return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g,
                    function (a, b) {
                        var r = entity[b];
                        return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
                    }
            );
        };
    }());
```

you are setting a property to String class[function]. So you can't do this

```
'any string'.deentityfy()
```

but you can

```
String.deentityfy()
```